# The operation can’t be completed because an unexpected error occurred (error code -50)

Tags: macos, file-copying

I was trying to copy a bunch of files from my iMac to my My Passport wifi drive. A certain folder kept failing. I rebooted, ran Disk Utility using a different mac, tried connecting directly (drive didn't show up!).

Since I couldn't find the answer by searching, I decided to post my solution now that I have solved it.

A few of the pdf files in my folder (saved from emails) had been named using the '/' character. The Mac had no problem saving these files locally. Obviously, that character represents a path in unix/linux/mac systems and so it probably was originally named on a Windoze machine.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: After removing the '/' in the filenames, all copy operations completed successfully.